# rails 4 semantic ui multi-select show user selections on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, multi-select, semantic-ui

I am trying to implement multi-select in a form in rails 4, using Semantic UI. I want users to be able to select multiple categories for each post. So far, I am able to display the dropdown select field which pulls all the categories from the database as follows:

```
<%= form_for @post, :html => {:class => "ui form bk-form group"}  do |f| %>
  <label>Post title:</label><br />
  <%= f.text_field :title, autofocus: true %>

  <label>Choose a category:</label><br />
  <%= f.select(:category_ids,options_for_select(Category.all.collect{|x| [x.name,x.id,class:'item']}),{prompt:'Select categories'}, multiple: true, class:'ui fluid dropdown selection multiple')%>
<% end %>
```

With this, I am able to create and save posts and the data is inserted in the database. However, when I try to edit an article, the pre-selected categories do not show. I have tried to set the `value: @post.categories` option in the select field and still cannot get the existing categories to show. Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

**UPDATED**
Models are as follows:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :post_categories
    has_many :categories, through: :post_categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :post_categories
    has_many :posts, through: :post_categories
end

class PostCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :category, :counter_cache => :posts_count
end
```

Then my posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_post, only: [:edit, :update, :show]

    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        @post.user = current_user
        if @post.save
           flash[:notice] = "Post was successfully created"
           redirect_to user_posts_path
        else
           flash[:alert] = "Oh Snap!! We could not save your post"
           render 'new'
        end
    end

def edit
end

def update
   if @post.update(post_params)
       flash[:notice] = "Post was successfully updated"
       redirect_to user_posts_path
   else
       flash[:alert] = "Oh Snap!! We could not update your post"
       render 'edit'
   end
end

private
    def post_params
       params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :published, :tag_list, category_ids: []) 
    end

    def set_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Comment: is `:category_ids` a database column? Please provide relevant controller code and model code

Comment: see my update with the models and controllers. There is a many-to-many relationship between posts and categories

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: use `current_user.posts.build(post_params)` instead of `post = Post.new; post.user = current_user`. Still figuring out your problem

Comment: might it be an issue with  `category_ids` vs `categories_ids` ? Could you check if `@post` has an attribute `category_ids` when it is created? Though it would probably raise errors on creation already